# [nodejs]How expressjs destroy the expired session?

Tags: node.js, session, express

While i was developing java web, there is a config in `web.xml` as following:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Which means the session will be destroyed in 15mins while the associated client (webbrowser) has not accessed the website. I can even use implement `HttpSessionListener` to have the hook for session lifecycle.

But when i am developing node web via `expressjs` with `express-session` and `connect-memcached` `memcached`. I didn't find anything about session lifecycle in `express-session`'s documentation.

So my question is, will `expressjs` or `express-session` destroy the session? When and how?

Comment: you are looking for `maxAge` cookie property in express-session and `ttl` property in connect-memcached

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another problem, i set `cookie.maxAge` to `7` days. But     i found that the session will be expired in 5 ~ 10 mins in production env. And all the other env works as expected. Do you have any clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
req.session = null;
```

Comment: The thing is without a hook as java web container did(HttpSessionListener), i don't know when should i destroy it?
Is this completely not a issue in node world?

Comment: @Howard - You don't have to destroy Express sessions yourself.  The sessions infrastructure will release them some time after they expire and then the garbage collector will clean them up.